# How create a salesforce flow for case updates when an email is sent to an external contact

Tags: visual-workflow

Looking for any possible help to develop a flow for the certain scenario.  Have used process builder.  Now we are using/migrating to flow and looking for guidance.  We have a field that is toggled to show a customer has been contacted.  I am trying to automate this using flow with the following steps.

1. If Case Owner equal Created By then check the customer contact box.
2. If Case owner does not equal created by move to next step.
3. The first email that is sent to an external contact from the case, then check the customer contact box.

Can this be accomplished in flow?  Any guidance or directions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yes, you can do those things (via the "record-triggered" flow option), but you'll probably want two separate flows: one on cases, and one on email messages.

Though, for (1), I'd note that for people using Communities, you'd want to be doing something more like "If (Created By > Contact ID) is blank" as your criterion to distinguish internal from customer users. I assume by the logic you're using there that you've already got some assignment rules set up for the email-to-case end of things.

The case flow will look something like this; you want it to trigger on creation:
[image: Case flow]

There's nothing on the second branch, because your (2) step is "do nothing". Technically you can slim it down even further by putting the conditions into the "entry conditions" part up top, but that makes it a less useful reference for (3).

For (3), you make a similar flow as for (1), but the base is on the "Email Message" object. Trigger is on creation as with the case flow, and your entry conditions should be "Incoming = False", and maybe "ParentID != null" if your email messages end up on things other than cases in your instance. (I'm not aware that they even can at the time of this writing, but hey, future-proofing)

The decision node yes/no options will instead be "is the (Parent > customer-contact) checkbox checked off yet", and for "no", well, you update that parent case to check it off.

Comment: Thanks, it worked well.